# Building a Charting Library on the JVM from Scratch

Tags: java, swing, javafx, graphics, jvm

I thought I would ask around here as there are a lot of experienced devs with much more understanding of the Java ecosystem than me.

So, I am looking to build a plotting library for some simulation data I am working on. This will consist of having some subset of matplotlib's functionality. From what I understand I can use the following on the JVM:

- JavaFX / Swing
- Java2d / java3d
- Java OpenGL

Could anyone kindly tell me if any of those are suitable for what I am intending to do, or suggest a better alternative?

I do not want to use an existing plotting library as this is for a project which prevents me from doing so. I can however use a lower level library to build higher level components.

Thanks!

Comment: How many Java libraries have you built so far? Are you sure you have the required expertise to build this one, considering you don't know which graphics library to choose?

Comment: I have not built any libraries so far. I definitely do not have the expertise yet, but I will need to, over the next few months, get up to speed and build something out. I will only need a subset of matplotlibs functionality though, which should make it manageable. I was hoping some experienced Java programmers could bounce their ideas of how they would approach this task for a noob like me

Comment: Useful: [Oracle Java Tutorials - 2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html). Another approach is using JavaFX, it will allow you do make a nice desktop Java application, see [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/).

Comment: thanks @Jesper, any thoughts on the strengths and weaknesses of both when building software? Both look like very useful links to me

Comment: The tutorial explains the graphics API included with Java by default. You can use this in a simple Swing application. JavaFX is more modern, more sophisticated, but probably a bit more complicated to use and is not included with Java, you'll need to add it as a separate library.

Comment: ok got it cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is based on Java2d (AFAICT), so that is definitely an option. You could start by looking at their code, understand their approach and then re-implement the pieces you need. Some will argue that in that case use the library, but as you stated you can't. But there is no shame in using what others have done.